# Separate documents return 2 array use mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have this documents

```
[
   {newsID: 'abc', hot: true, category: { name: '123' }, date: 12434234234}},
   {newsID: 'hgd', hot: false, category: { name: '123' }, date: 425432212312},
   .....
]
```

First, I filter this document by the same category.name use aggregate like this

```
const newsData = Db.Collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "category.name": '123'}}
])
```

Anyway to separate this document to 2 arrays, filter by "hot" field true or false. And sort by "date" field foreach array. Use aggregate of MongoDB

The result I need

```
{
    hotNews: [
        {newsID: 'abc', hot: true, category: { name: '123' }, date: 12434234234},//hot: true
        ...
    ],
    news: [
        {newsID: 'hgd', hot: false, category: { name: '123' }, date: 425432212312},//hot: false
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: `$addFields` (or `$project`) with `$filter` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `$facet` stage to allow executing multiple pipelines within a query. This would allow you to have different fields (`hotNews` and `news`) that have different datasets.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "category.name": "123"
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      hotNews: [
        {
          $match: {
            hot: true
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            date: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      news: [
        {
          $match: {
            hot: false
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            date: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BFByZdmIDno)

Comment: That great, thank you. $facet solved the problem. Too many pipelines of aggregate MongoDB.  So, I don't know what should be use. More knowledge about aggregation MongoDB, thank you so much.